# Why I can't forward port 8500 on host machine with consul image?

Tags: macos, docker

I try to run [Consul image](http://hub.docker.com/_/consul/) on Mac forwarding 8500 port for simple tests.
My command to run the image is:

> docker run -it -p 8500:8500 consul agent -server -bootstrap 0.0.0.0

I do not use `--net=host` since it does not work on Mac so I try to forward 8500.

When I try to telnet from my Mac the connection gets immediately closed:

```
user$ telnet localhost 8500
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Or when I try to add a new value I get:

```
consul kv put foo bar
Error! Failed writing data: Put http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/foo: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: getsockopt: connection refused
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Also, the --net=host argument works fine on Mac ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried what you have posted and seems that the port 8500 is opened

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                      NAMES
f4ac8a5233e2        consul              "docker-entrypoint..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        8300-8302/tcp, 8301-8302/udp, 8600/tcp, 8600/udp, 0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp   sharp_knuth
```

And I get this:

```
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to dev-consul
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

However, it is running as you can see from the logs:

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Consul agent running!
           Version: 'v0.9.3'
           Node ID: '27998add-58f9-e424-84a0-038db228629f'
         Node name: '68bfdf141e7f'
        Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '<all>')
            Server: true (Bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: 0.0.0.0 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
      Cluster Addr: 127.0.0.1 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
           Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false

==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [DEBUG] Using random ID "27998add-58f9-e424-84a0-038db228629f" as node ID
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] raft: Initial configuration (index=1): [{Suffrage:Voter ID:127.0.0.1:8300 Address:127.0.0.1:8300}]
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] raft: Node at 127.0.0.1:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state (Leader: "")
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 68bfdf141e7f.dc1 127.0.0.1
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 68bfdf141e7f 127.0.0.1
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] consul: Adding LAN server 68bfdf141e7f (Addr: tcp/127.0.0.1:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] consul: Handled member-join event for server "68bfdf141e7f.dc1" in area "wan"
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] agent: Started DNS server 0.0.0.0:8600 (udp)
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] agent: Started DNS server 0.0.0.0:8600 (tcp)
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] agent: Started HTTP server on [::]:8500
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [WARN] raft: Heartbeat timeout from "" reached, starting election
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] raft: Node at 127.0.0.1:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state in term 2
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [DEBUG] raft: Votes needed: 1
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [DEBUG] raft: Vote granted from 127.0.0.1:8300 in term 2. Tally: 1
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] raft: Election won. Tally: 1
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] raft: Node at 127.0.0.1:8300 [Leader] entering Leader state
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] consul: cluster leadership acquired
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [DEBUG] consul: Skipping self join check for "68bfdf141e7f" since the cluster is too small
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] consul: member '68bfdf141e7f' joined, marking health alive
    2017/10/02 20:26:27 [INFO] consul: New leader elected: 68bfdf141e7f
    2017/10/02 20:26:28 [INFO] agent: Synced node info
    2017/10/02 20:27:27 [DEBUG] consul: Skipping self join check for "68bfdf141e7f" since the cluster is too small
    2017/10/02 20:27:34 [DEBUG] agent: Node info in sync
```

Comment: Result is the same